# Javascript: Accessing parent properties from inside nested function

Tags: javascript

How to access `somevar:'this is Foo'` from inside `bar.foo()` ?

```
function Foo(){
    this.somevar='this is Foo';
}
Foo.prototype={
    bar:{
        somevar:'this is bar'
        ,foo:function(){
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
}

var instance = new Foo();
instance.bar.foo();
```

Here is link to jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jct8n/3/

Comment: You can just access `Foo.prototype.somevar` - or do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @Lucero - That approach should work except that if someone does `var foo = new Foo();` and then `foo.somevar = 'newValue'`, calling `foo()` would still print 'this is Foo' instead of 'newValue'.

Comment: @Beck You want the members of `prototype` objects to be methods. Adding objects which itself contain methods doesn't sound like a good pattern.

Comment: Yea, guess that's my mistake. I'll have to create separate class instead of nested object. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think perhaps the scoping rules of the language will not allow this in any straightforward way.  The best suggestion I can come up with to get what you want (short of renaming `somevar` to get rid of the clash in the first place) is to use `apply()` to change the value of `this` inside of `foo()`, like:

```
var instance = new Foo();
instance.bar.foo.apply(instance);
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jct8n/2/

Comment: Well yea, passing as parameter is an option. But it's madness to pass it on each method inside nested object. And what if both contexts are required? :S

Comment: @Beck The `this` value provides you with one context. If you want another one, you'll need to pass it in as an argument...

Answer (score 2):

I use this method for public and private instance variables:

http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/14/javascript-how-to-get-private-privileged-public-and-static-members-properties-and-methods/

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(Foo.prototype.somevar);
```

Alternatively, you should consider just renaming one of the `somevar` variables to easily allow for what you're looking to do, as well as eliminating some complexity and confusion.

Comment: And how to access property from current instance only?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend just using the 2nd part of this answer - rename one of the `somvar` variables to eliminate the clash.